# jQuery not working? How to Write Reuseable jQuery in angular 7

Tags: jquery, angular

I am working on a website which uses jQuery and then use OWL carousel.

When I include a `.js` file in angular to initiate owl carousel it works fine but when I navigate to another route it stops works.

I want to execute the same jquery code on every component. I already use `ngOnInit` which throws error owl() not found.

`ngAfterViewInit` nothing happens.

Question is how to write a code which we can use on every page of the angular app?

code i write in ngOnInit or ngAfterViewInit

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    responsiveClass:true,
    loop: true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1,
            nav:true
        },
        600:{
            items:3,
            nav:true
        },
        1000:{
            items:4,
            nav:true,
        }
    }
});
```

if I put above code in any js file and include after jquery and owl execute it works only one time

Comment: can you provide your code and the error you receive ?

Comment: Can you please explain more. Still not get it

Comment: if i write a code in js file and include in angular.json it works only 1 time ... means if i navigate to another route and go back to that route again e.g from home -> about then again about -> home the slider stops.

Comment: Instead of jQuery you should use [ngx-owl-carousel-o](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-owl-carousel-o)

Comment: @Satpal if i want to use another plugin which works on jQuery and if it's not available then is there any possible way to write flexible code ?

Comment: Yes it's the better suggestion @Satpal